# re-open a closed question that received 1k views

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9886/civilizations-evolution-with-common-technologies-like-pyramids-in-egyptian-and-a)
 reached 1082 view however it is closed , If I did some review and modification on it , can you re-open it ?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't a close voter, so I can't speak for them. However, this question looks to me like an example of [this kind of question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/642/771) (from our [Why did I get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-i-get-a-downvote) meta question). As you can see from the large number of votes that answer got, this is a pet peeve of a lot of users here.

Yes, in theory you could edit the question to make it fit site policies. In practice, I doubt that's feasible without completely ditching the speculative nature of the question.

Probably the best you could do would to be to remove most of the justifying material, and just ask something along the lines of "Why did so many supposedly isolated societies develop similar-looking pyramids?"

Comment: That question had some attention regarding the people who view it , so I asked my self why I dont improve it to make it better , anyway ill check your comments and see how I can improve it

Comment: @moudiz IMHO, that would be nice, as I rather like both of the answers posted. 1K views, while quite respectable, is not exactly a world-beater here though. For example, [this question](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/21621/why-didnt-europe-support-the-byzantine-empire-against-the-turks) asked yesterday has nearly 700 already.

Comment: I am not saying its world beater but I though it had some attention while its closed.