# Can we adjust the help center to help manage scope?

Tags: discussion

Our [help center](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for don't ask is pretty generic.  I have some [opinions](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3564/1401) about out of scope questions. Is there a way to adjust the help center with a better "out of scope" test? Would that reduce the chances of History = landfill?

(We have this problem on PM:SE as well - is this a problem across all sites?  Do people ask questions about meerkats on the python stack exchange?  Is History special?)

Comment: Well, I did notice this morning someone posting a question that was 100% unabashedly economics on the politics site. Thinking about it, the fact that the two were equated in the poster's mind should be a huge red flag ...

Comment: @T.E.D. Just imagine if there was a history of economics question on history of science!

Comment: @axsvl77 - That would be dismal

Answer (score 2):

As near as I can tell from poking around through our help center and meta.so, the only page in the entire help center that is moderator editable is the [on-topic page](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So if there's something we want tweaked, it would have to be phrased in a way that allows us to put in there.

Thinking about it, this might be a good place to link in our [Why did I get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-i-get-a-downvote?noredirect=1&lq=1) meta question we are constantly referring back to.

Comment: ?? Really?? Only one page?  That does explain a lot.  Do you think it is worth the effort to try to edit that page?  I'm a jaded, cynical old coot and I suspect that the people using H:SE as a landfill aren't reading the page,  but if there are younger, more optimistic types out there I'd be willing to try to propose something.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - We've edited it before to clarify things. In fact, I think I'm going to do it right now to make the "Its not about ... mythology" entry link out to the Mythology site.