# Comments vanishing?

Tags: support

I noticed a few comments on [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55929/why-did-the-english-name-of-pacific-ocean-stick-if-it-has-been-known-by-many-c) have vanished.   I'm curious why.  They all seemed innocuous.  (Mine was just a link to another Stack Exchange Site.)

[image]

I know the question is closed anyway.  I'm just confused because I don't think I've seen random comments vanish without a trace like that before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess, but that comment might have suffered from being adjacent to several other comments that were in need of deletion.  IMHO it makes much the same point as one of mine, but does it with far better backup.

However, there are also (IMHO) far too many comments on that question as-is, so if anything probably *more* should be deleted. I've just gone and done my part by deleting mine (kind of made obsolete by my answer anyway), and the replies to it.

Understand that *answers* are our goal here, and [comments are just barn cats](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/when-comments-are-flagged-are-related-comments-looked-at-by-moderators/3631#3631).

Comment: Were they *really* "in need"? You had one there and I as well, & mine was meant to be read together with the one still under your A to improve that A. I find a bit sad that we do not seem to get it re-opened, while half a dozen relevant comments and half-answers there disappear (I have no idea how many altogether). Especially semaphores is in the wrong box, Alex and luiz might be expanded. That is all a very unsatisfactory status.