# Some of my comments that I believe relevant have been deleted

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

Three years ago I posted a question about a Confederate flag obscure design .

[Flag with 13 white stars and a crescent on red background](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/38833/flag-with-13-white-stars-and-a-crescent-on-red-background)

At first there were some votes to close it (at first I didn't really know that it whas a Confederate flag either) but it turned out to be an acceptable question that had an excellent answer.

When I accepted the answer I made some compliments to the answerer for his effort. I usually do this and they usually don't get deleted. These complimentary comments were a bit longer than usual, but the reason was that they contained additional information about some of the flag's details, such as its gold trim.

Actually, this is not a complaint. They were not very important comments and were made three years ago, but I would like to know if there is a definite protocol on this type of "thank you for your response" comments.

Comment: Related question: https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/when-comments-are-flagged-are-related-comments-looked-at-by-moderators . See in particular [Comments are our barn cats](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/when-comments-are-flagged-are-related-comments-looked-at-by-moderators/3631#3631)

Comment: Some of the people I deem relevant to my life have been *deleted*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I should make it clear that all the action being discussed here happened 4 years ago. I wasn't one of the mods doing the work on this one. Some of the principals are no longer active on this site.

Looking through that answer, there appear to be 9 deleted comments. They mostly appear to be in 4 categories:

1. (1) Comment deleted by its own author, presumably due to desire to edit it after it had been posted for >5 mins.
2. (1) "attaboy" comment from the OQ, made superfluous by the fact that OQ also accepted the answer.
3. (1) "Why I upvoted" comment.
4. (6) Discussion about (2) tangentially related issues.

In general, our bias here isn't toward keeping comments, and I can see a reasonable case for deleting all of these. Could one *also* make a case for keeping some of them? I suppose. But remember these are just comments, not proper posts. Their reason for existing is to help improve posts. Try not to get too attached to [the barn cats](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/when-comments-are-flagged-are-related-comments-looked-at-by-moderators/3631#3631).