# What is the purpose of the 'Add another answer' button?

Tags: discussion, answers

Seeing as I can edit any answer I post to my heart's content (assuming it hasn't been deleted), I'm wondering why this button is needed - or is it there precisely for this reason (answer deleted)?

I haven't noticed anyone posting two answers, other than spammers e.t.c. trying to defy a moderator. Has anyone here used it (for a legitimate reason of course)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a network wide feature, [meant to allow the same user to provide two different, perhaps contradictory or incompatible options to the same question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) It's not a *particularly* useful for the main History.SE site, because most of our questions deal with historical facts. Answers should strive to provide a full answer to a question, so if there are two explanations for a historical event, a good answer should incorporate both of them.

In contrast, on some other sites - including our meta site - question can be more subjective or be solved in multiple ways. For example, suppose we have a meta question on what to do with the tags [united-states](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [united-states-of-america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states-of-america). I could post one answer advocating that we merge the latter into the former, and another advocating merging the former into the latter.

Both are valid options, so by posting both, the community is able to vote on which solution we prefer. It basically means we don't have to wait for someone else to come along and champion an opposing view.

Comment: I figured this feature might have something to do with other sites, and I can see your point about more subjective questions. Useful example too.

Answer (score 5):

I have occasionally posted two answers, based on either differing interpretations, or assumptions, or because the Q&A has revealed new facets, or because a year later I am aware of new research.

Comment: Mark's being perhaps a bit overly humble here. He in fact did exactly this in this meta's single most referenced question: [Why did I get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-i-get-a-downvote) . As of this writing, 13 of the answers are his posts.

Comment: @T.E.D. Your mention of Mark's post reminds me of the recent moderator election...

Answer (score 2):

I have posted two answers to one post, partly because I received new and highly relevant information from a professional, which I wished to quote at length, and partly because, with limited technology at the time - it was frankly easier!

[Did any English duke ever grant away an earldom he held?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26695/did-any-english-duke-ever-grant-away-an-earldom-he-held/26861#26861)

Comment: OK, easier is good reason!