# Why do reputation-points allow negative hits from members?

Tags: discussion

This just makes reputation points into a popularity-contest, simply suppressing dissension by opinions rather than facts.

Comment: This question isn't really specific to the History site, so it probably belongs over on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think that instead of "suppressing dissension" it wants dissension to be proved by research evidence.

Comment: Disagreement is not argument.

Comment: Are you talking about this meta site? Or the main site? Is there a particular incident?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*).

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of down-votes is explained in our [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

> Voting down, also known as "casting downvotes", is how the community indicates which questions and answers are least useful.

It is part of the SE 'gamification' model (searching for `gamification` on [Meta:SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) will give you more background about this model).

---

For questions, the reasons for down-votes are indicated by the tooltip on the down-vote button:

> "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

(place your cursor over the down-vote button to see the tool-tip)

Similarly, for answers, the tool-tip states:

> This answer is not useful.

Of course, the 'usefulness' of an answer is almost always going to be subjective!  As a rule, you can make answers more 'useful' by ensuring that all assertions are supported by citations from reputable sources.

Our Help centre contains a page, [How do I write a good answer?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), which you might also find helpful.

---

More specific to this site, you might find the information contained in the threads:

[Why did my question get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/618/24858)

and

[Why did my answer get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/why-did-my-answer-get-a-downvote)

here on meta to be helpful.

Comment: But reputation-points determine whether a person will be permitted to post on other answers, so it's just propaganda.

Comment: @TomEvans No. Reputation points unlock [privileges](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).  They limit what anyone is able to do on the site.  In effect, they are a measure of trust from the community.  As I said in my answer, you might find it informative to learn about the gamification model on Meta:SE.

Comment: @ sempaiscuba By "trust from the community." you  _conformity_ to community prejudices.
You might find it informative to learn about intellectual honesty and dogma.