# Why have I got many downvotes on my second question?

Tags: discussion

I’m asking this because, I have asked a simple question in here [*”Questions about Thracia*”](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/48133/27014) and then all sudden, I got downvotes. For what? It was not even necessary to downvote. If I got 7 downvotes that’s mean there are some mistakes there, so where are they? I just listed them because, I have read on internet saying such and such this, and I wanted to know if it is 100% true what I read, that’s it.

Yes, I agree that this site it is forbidden:

1. Swearings
2. Fighting
3. Saying nonsense
4. Not giving correct answer
5. To ask a question that has a lot of mistakes
6. To write an answer without sharing the sites from where you brought it up as an evidence.
7. Making fun of others

And many more...

But this time, why? Can those who have down-voted my second question, explain to me in here the right reason for doing this? Just to know.

The main reasons I want I asked this, is because, I want to know about my ancestors, what they did and so on. Oh, and this is the last one. Is it true that Siberia is a relative with Romania?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not one of those that downvoted, so I won't post here as an answer, but I suspect the comment on your question about lack of prior research (by SJuan76) may be something you want to take on board.

Comment: @sempaiscuba well I have researched and I tried to find out if it is 100% true what I read, and that’s why I was asking in this site.

Comment: In addition, you might find the meta post [Why did my question get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/618/24858) contains a lot of helpful guidance.

Comment: @sempaiscuba well, the problem is, the sources I found out is, that it is written in Romanian and I don’t think can read Romanian.

Comment: You may well have researched, but that isn't detailed in your question.  Where did you read those claims?  Where have you already checked to find out if what you read was true?  Why do you doubt those sources?

Comment: @sempaiscuba Because, there might be some liers on internet who writes posts just to trick others and I don’t want that, I want an evidence from a book. I thought that in here everyone speaks English and don’t know no one to speak Romanian, so I thoughts it is worthless to put a link, because no one can understand. I have read it on Google, and when I read it, I had some doubts and I wanted to ask you this for verifying if it is true or false.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that people won't understand.  You would probably be surprised by the range of languages spoken by people who use this site.  Your question should be in English, but if the only sources you have are in Romanian you should still cite them.  But there also sources in English/German/French/Italian/Greek etc.  Just for one obvious example, what was wrong with the information in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thracia), and the references cited there?

Comment: @AlexA: They are very far from being perfect, but an automated translator might well allow an English speaker to at least see the general gist of a foreign language reference. Also, many of our contributors are from outside North America, and know multiple languages. Don't assume that an English language site is completely restricted to English resources. I have translated over 50 pages of [*Saski's **The 1809 Campaign***](https://archive.org/details/campagnedeenall00goog/page/n4) for my own benefit, despite having only rudimentary French.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for others, but I downvoted your question due to an apparent lack of research and citations. Also, the (mostly frankly hard to believe) claims make the question seem like there is an agenda behind it.

I could find no references online to Thrace occupying Algeria, and the claim that "Thracia occupied all England and they have made cities and many things there", plus the fact that the question is extremely broad, made me vote to close as well.

Actually, I don't usually downvote and vote to close - in fact, I try hard to avoid both. As your question here on meta seems to be a genuine attempt to understand why your question was so poorly received (which makes me think that you do *not* actually have an agenda), I've removed my downvote. However, I cannot vote to reopen as there are too many problems with your question.

First, you to limit your question to Thrace in relation to one country or area. Then, you need to cite the source of the claim in the question and (if possible) mention another source that supports it.

Next, you should do some googling to see what other sources say. A good place to start is Wikipedia; it's not perfect, but it's a good place to start and most of the articles have been written in good faith and have sources and footnotes.

So, if you want to know about your ancestors, I suggest you start with Wikipedia and work from there. If you find information there that is unclear or which contradicts other sources you have seen, then you can begin to write a question. For example, you could look at my question [Did the Romans eat breakfast?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/45466/did-the-romans-eat-breakfast). Also, look at other people's questions, especially more recent ones that got a lot of votes (although some questions get a lot of votes because the topic is popular rather than because the question is good).

You can also ask questions if you want to know more than you have been able to find. For example, you read that King XXX died in battle but there is no information on which battle or where it took place (so you could ask about that battle). Have a look at this question: [Why did the Royal Society in 1771 believe that a continent further south than Australia should exist?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/47683/why-did-the-royal-society-in-1771-believe-that-a-continent-further-south-than-au).

Finally, follow the advice that sempaiscuba gave in his comments. He is a moderator and a very good contributor on this site so he knows what he is talking about!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I only waited to see the users who downvoted my second question to answer in Meta so that I can understand what’s wrong with it. Thanks for your advice, next time, I’ll try not to repeat the same mistake.